# How to emphasize that something has not changed (greater or smaller)?

Tags: phrase-request

How to emphasize that something has not changed (greater or smaller) in a way like:

*Something is still the same* **not greater nor smaller**. (OR **nor greater neither smaller** OR ???)

*Something has not changed* **not greater nor smaller**.

Comment: What's wrong with just *still the same*? Or even *still the same size*?

Comment: Unchanged works - "Something is still unchanged"

Comment: @JasonBassford , to emphasize

Comment: @JohnFeltz , thanks. Updated question: it's not about synonyms of 'not changed'

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko I don't understand. Not changed means not changed, the direction of change (greater/smaller, positive/negative) is irrelevant.  Since.. it... hasn't changed.

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko This is still unclear. To emphasize a lack of change, I might say that it has *really* not changed. And I still don't know why *still the same size* is less appropriate if size must be specifically mentioned.

Comment: If you are trying to emphasize the lack of change, then you can say something like 'precisely'.  "Something is still precisely the same size."

Comment: Can you give us the actual context that you want to use this. It seems that "unchanged" is the answer, perhaps emphasised with an adverb: "completely" or "absolutely" but an actual context would make it clear if those are appropriate or not.

Comment: It isn't really required in modern English, but if you want to use "nor" in the future the pattern is "Neither X nor Y". "Nor X neither Y" is not correct. There might be some situations when "nor" could be used without "neither" at all, but those are even less common.

Comment: In conversational contexts we would say something like *It's still exactly the same size.* if we have been asked (perhaps repeatedly) whether the size of something has changed at all. In more formal contexts we'd could say *Its size **has remained constant**.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which words you use depend greatly on what you are talking about.  Quantities can *become* greater or smaller, but you can also say that they *increase* or *decrease*.

> The trade deficit between the two countries **neither increased nor decreased** during the first fiscal quarter.

Meanwhile, if talking about *physical* dimensions of something, then it may be more idiomatic to say it got *larger* or *smaller*.

> I am happy to note that after the cruise my belly did not get any **larger**.  Of course, it didn't get any **smaller**, either.  (my belly got **neither larger nor smaller**)

Alternately you can express the change in size by using *grow* and *shrink*.

> My belly **neither grew nor shrank** after going on the cruise.

Other verbs are possible, and may be more idiomatic, but you have to give us specifics.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what “something” refers to, but I’d  suggest:

> not larger or smaller

Answer (score 1):

The full phrase I would use (given that you absolutely want additional emphasis on the lack of size change) would be:

> *Something* is unchanged, neither larger nor smaller.

Specific notes:

- Using "larger" instead of "greater" is the more intuitive antonym for "smaller".
- "Neither X nor Y" is appropriate here, especially since you want the emphasis.
- "the same" feels awkward without being "the same as something else". It's understandable with implied "the same as before", but it feels redundant when combined with "still".
- "still unchanged" could be used if you want to indicate a significant history of reports that are all "unchanged".
- There could be some additional appropriate changes depending on what exactly the "something" is and what context surrounds the sentence.

All of this is dependent on an assumption though: the sentence you were trying to make was constructed to indicate some physical object did not change its size. In the event that your meaning was instead "some quantity did not go up or down" then the construction differs. For example:

> The boiler pressure hasn't increased or decreased.

The phrase "hasn't increased or decreased" would be a reasonable phrase for any quantifiable trait, including size, as long as it's stated. For another example:

> *Something*'s size hasn't increased or decreased

Is a reasonable way to communicate the same meaning as the original sentence.